# Find in hasMany where all Conditions are true

Tags: cakephp-2.0, has-many

I have this tables:

products -> hasMany -> categories

Table: products

```
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Prod 1 |
|  2 | Prod 2 |
|  3 | Prod 3 |
+----+--------+
```

Table: categories

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | title | product_id |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | Cat 1 |          1 |
|  2 | Cat 2 |          1 |
|  3 | Cat 3 |          2 |
|  4 | Cat 1 |          1 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

How can i query the products which are in both categories "Cat 1" AND "Cat 2" in my example i want only find "Prod 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition is that you should change the database, so you instead have a habtm relation.

So your tables should looks like this:

```
Products (id, title)
ProductCategories (product_id, category_id)
Categories (id, title)
```

So the product can belong to many categories.

Then you can look up your table for products belonging to category with ID = 1 and category with ID = 3, by doing following query:

**MySQL query**

```
SELECT Products.id, Products.title 
FROM Products
WHERE 
Products.id IN 
(
   SELECT c1.product_id 
   FROM ProductCategories AS c1 
     INNER JOIN ProductCategories AS c2
     ON c1.product_id = c2.product_id
   WHERE c1.category_id = 1 AND c2.category_id = 3
);
```

Comment: ok - looks good.For now i have max 5 category_ids to match so i extended your suggestion and had 5 inner joins. But what happens if you want to scale this and have 25  category_ids you want to match.

Comment: Yeah I understand your issue, and I have thought the same, but as far as now, I havn't got a smart solution of that.. 

In CakePHP your could perhaps do some concatenation of the query string for all the categories.. Like

foreach($categories as $category){ $query.= $inner_join_for_this_category; }

$query; // Now contains inner joins for all